# what is static and dynamic L-PDU in the AUTOSAR CANIF

Tags: autosar, automotive

what the use of the static and dynamic L-PDUS in the com stack of AUTOSAR, and when will be using (please provide one example), if i was not configured how will i know its dynamic or static L-PDU.

Answer (score 1):

Static L-PDUs are defined with their ID and can not be changed later. Dynamic L-PDUs can be changed at runtime regarding their CanId. For Dynamic L-PDUs you need to also enable the DynamicTx API e.g. `CanIf_SetDynamicTxId()` and use it for setting the actual CanId.

I would suggest, reading chapters 7.3, 7.4 (and also the Abbreviation/Acronyms) in the AUTOSAR_SWS_CanInterface.pdf.
Also, ch. 10 usually explains the configuration elements.